# Nginx rewrite URL path of .jp domain to use Japanese characters instead of alphabet

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

To make the URL paths more accessible to Japanese visitors, I tried configuring nginx to rewrite URLs for visitors of the .jp domain of my website using Japanese characters. Running on Ubuntu 18.04 server with nginx 1.17.3

For example:

domain.jp/About ---> domain.jp/会社案内

or

domain.jp/topic1/section3 ---> domain.jp/トピック1/section3

So only the first level should be using Japanese characters.

I tried it with the following rewrite in the default file:

```
location ~ /About/(.*)$ {
         rewrite ^ /会社案内/$1?$args permanent;
        }
```

I would write location blocks in a similar way for all remaining paths, but currently not even the About redirect works. I did restart nginx after saving.
Other contents of the default file that might be relevant:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name someDomains w$
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;


        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name someDomains w$
        root /srv/www/domain.co.jp/Website;

gzip...

brotli...
   
location /  {
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:8080;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I tried starting more simple, but it only resulted in a 404 when trying to visit /About

```
        location /About {
         rewrite ^/About?$ /会社案内 break;
        }
```

**EDIT2:**
I was pretty confident it would work with this, but it also resulted in 404. Which makes me wonder if my goal is even doable with Nginx or if I have to write separate routes in the backend site of my website, listening to the Japanese URLs..?

```
 location ~ /About {
    rewrite ^/About/(.*)  /会社案内/$1 break;
       }
```

Comment: Have you tried the case-insensitive matcher `~*`?

Comment: @RezartQelibari
Not yet, as the Japanese characters don't use upper/lower case and I know the exact name of the existing paths

Comment: The case-insensitive matcher matches agains the english url. So /About and /about are usually two different URLs, if your file system is case-sensitive. That matcher matches both.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do. Does user type `/About` and the browser changes to `/会社案内`? Or does the user type `/会社案内` and your server silently converts it and sends it upstream as `/About`? Does your server know how to process `/About` and `/会社案内`? Your first attempt fails because `$1` is undefined.

Comment: @RichardSmith
I was thinking of the 2nd case, if that is even possible? My server currently only listens to /About. For UX I was trying to achieve that the URL is displayed in Japanese characters when users are visiting the Japanese website, but in the background it is processed with alphabet characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to internally redirect the URI `/トピックfoo` to `/topicfoo` and the URI `/会社案内` to `/About`. An internal redirection means that Nginx changes the URI without generating a 3xx response, which would cause the browser's address bar also to change.

An internal redirection is achieved using a `rewrite...last` or `rewrite...break`, and also the final parameter of a `try_files` statement. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite).

For example:

```
location = /会社案内 {
    rewrite ^ /About last;
}
location /トピック {
    rewrite /トピック(.*)$ /topic$1 last;
}
```

If you have a number of these translations, you may want to seek a solution using a `map` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map);

Comment: Thank you so much, works like a charm. Never considered writing the internal URL as location. Thank you also for the hint using map, I'll have a look.